# Finding $y=Ae^{kt}$ given $dy/dt$ at two points.

Tags: exponential-function

How can I find the exponential growth equation, specifically $A$, the initial value and k when given

$dy/dt = 12.2$ at $t=1$

$dy/dt = 20.36$ at $t=8$

Comment: $y'=kAe^{kt}$ now try plugging in those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
y = Ae^{kt} \implies y' = kAe^{kt}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
y'\Big|_{t = 1} &= kAe^k = 12.2\tag{1} \\
y'\Big|_{t = 8} &= kAe^{8k} = 20.36\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
$(2)/(1)$,
$$\begin{align}
e^{7k} &= \dfrac{20.36}{12.2} \\
7k\ln e &= \ln\left(\dfrac{20.36}{12.2}\right) \\
k &\approx 0.0732
\end{align}$$
Plug $k$ in $(1)$ [or $(2)$] to find $A$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\frac{\mathtt{d}}{\mathtt{d}t}y=Ake^{kt}$.
We know $Ake^{k}=v_1$ and $Ake^{8k}=v_2$. Thus potentiating and dividing:
$$\frac{\left(Ak\right)^8 \cdot e^{8k}}{Ak \cdot e^{8k} }=\left(Ak\right)^7=\frac{v_1^8}{v_2}$$
We now know $Ak$.
From $\frac{v_1}{Ak}=e^k$ we can calculate $k$ and finally $A$.

Specifically:
$Ak = \left(\frac{v_1^8}{v_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{7}}=11.339$

Comment: But $AKe^{8k}/Ake^k$ does not equal $(Ak)^8/Ak$.....

Comment: ok, ok, i will be more explicit...